# Upgrade guide for Kohana 3.0.9 (from 3.0.8)

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Is there an upgrade guide for Kohana 3.0.9 from 3.0.8. I'm looking for something like what [jQuery provides](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/11/jquery-1-4-4-release-notes/) when they release a new version. It allows for a quick scan of the changes to notice if there's anything I could use or would change how I've done things.

The resolved issues are part of this, but I'm looking for something more high level. The issues require reading everything in each issue and it's often hard to understand what's actually changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3.0.x are minor releases and should have no breaking API changes. Nothing else to add really.

**Note** If you're using the core as a submodule then you can switch between versions and make sure everything works as expected. Rolling back is as easy as checking out a git branch.

Comment: If you are not using git to manage your repository, upgrading is done by copying the new release's `system` and `modules` directory on top of your existing application. Compare `index.php` and `application/bootstrap.php` for any changes.

Answer (score 0):

Changes can be seen in redmine
http://dev.kohanaframework.org/projects/kohana3/roadmap

Check "Show completed versions" for older issues.

Comment: I was looking for something more like what jQuery provides so I don't need to open up each one to figure out what was changed and if it will affect me. Even doing that with the roadmap doesn't help because it doesn't tell you what has actually changed (unless someone put it in there). What I ended up doing was doing a file compare for files/classes that I've extended.